# How do I silence squeaky springs on a 2006 VW Golf?

Tags: vw, golf, springs, suspension

I have a 2006 VW Golf and my front two springs are squeaky like bed springs.  I have tried spraying them down with WD40 but it doesn't help.  Some seasons they are quiet other times (I believe more in the summer months) every little bump causes them to squeak.

Is there anything I can put on them to silence them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of that car, so I'm going to take a stab and assume we're talking about coil springs.

Springs only squeak where they contact something else, which is why spraying them didn't help. If you can't see anything else in contact with the spring have a look at the top and bottom seats. Those seats sometimes wear. Not necessarily all the way through but enough to make the part where the spring sits uneven, resulting in movement.

Sometimes, if the suspension has been worked on for any reason, the springs and seats may not have been quite correctly matched up when it was put back together, again resulting in movement. That movement causes squeaks.

Comment: the 2006 Golf does use coil springs if you want to mod that first sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the springs are the source of the squeaking? It could be some other moving part of the front suspension, perhaps with a worn bushing.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that WD40 is not a lubricant. It's a desiccant. You might have better luck using lithium grease on the parts that you can get at. Penetrating oil (BP Blaster) will help on the bushings you can't easily access. You might have to unbolt the suspension components to get at the bushings and spring seats in order to hose them down with lube (if the problem persists).

Comment: WD40 is not a dessicant. Dessicants absorb water, WD40 displaces (repels?) water.